# Can I use htaccess to redirect requests to the domain name to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

I have changed the A record for domainname.com to point to the IP address of subdomain.domainname.com. That's working.

Now, I'd like to change the htaccess so that any requests made to domainname.com are redirected to subdomain.domainname.com/subdirectory

Is this possible? And if so, what's the command please?

Comment: what webserver are you using? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using [Name based Virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), but if you want to use a .htaccess file something along the following lines will do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^domainname.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/subdirectory
RewriteRule .*              /subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```